# REQUEST_DENIED for Google matrix API

Tags: python, google-api

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. My API is enabled.

This is my code:

```
# importing required libraries
import requests, json

# enter your api key here
api_key = 'API KEY'

# Take source as input
source = 'h4n1g1'

# Take destination as input
dest = 'h4n1p8'

# url variable store url 
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'

# Get method of requests module
# return response object
r = requests.get(url + 'origins = ' + source +
                 '&destinations = ' + dest +
                 '&key = ' + api_key)

# json method of response object
# return json format result
x = r.json()

# by default driving mode considered

# print the value of x
print(x)
```

The Google distance API works fine, but not the matrix API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erase those spaces before the equal, if I where you I would also erase the space after the equal.

```
r = requests.get(url + 'origins=' + source +
             '&destinations= ' + dest +
             '&key=' + api_key)
```